# JS array inside an array - Adding a new "mini-array"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array

Add element in array embedded in array - Javascript
I have the following array:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

, and within that array, every array inside looks like this:

```
0 : {_id: "bla", header: "test", time: "test PM", content: "test", uniqueid: "test"}
    1: {_id: "blay", header: "tests", time: "tests PM", content: "even more tests", uniqueid: "tests"}
    2: {_id: "awa", header: "sd", time: 3:14:15 PM", content: "sdf", uniqueid: "sdfg"}
```

My question is, how would I insert another "mini-array" inside of this big array, at position 0, with header: finaltest, time: finalTest PM, content: thefinaltest, and uniqueid: testt ?

I was thinking maybe using .unshift, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What are you not sure about ? [unshift](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add element in array embedded in JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351281/add-element-in-array-embedded-in-js-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi do you mean something like this ?

```
let table = [
  {_id: "bla", header: "test", time: "test PM", content: "test", uniqueid: "test"},
  {_id: "blay", header: "tests", time: "tests PM", content: "even more tests", uniqueid: "tests"},
  {_id: "awa", header: "sd", time: "3:14:15 PM", content: "sdf", uniqueid: "sdfg"}
   ]


let newRow = {_id: "bl@@@@", header: "finaltest", time: "finalTest PM", content: "test", uniqueid: "testt"};

table.unshift(newRow);


console.log(table);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new array rather than mutating the existing one, you can use the spread operator:

```js
const originalArray = [{}, {}, {}, {}]
const newObj = { some: 'values' }

const newArray = [newObj, ...originalArray]
```

Result:

```
// newArray
[{ some: 'values' }, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method can help. It's as simple as that:

```js
const data = [
    { _id: "bla", header: "test", time: "test PM", content: "test", uniqueid: "test" },
    { _id: "blay", header: "tests", time: "tests PM", content: "even more tests", uniqueid: "tests" },
    { _id: "awa", header: "sd", time: "3:15 PM", content: "sdf", uniqueid: "sdfg" }
];

const inserted_obj = { _id: "inserted", header: "finaltest", time: "finalTest PM", content: "thefinaltest", uniqueid: "testt" };

let start = 0;
let deleteCount = 0;
data.splice(start, deleteCount, inserted_obj);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) seems like the way to go to add it to the 0 position.

Should you want to add it to the end of the array, use [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

To add it to a specific position, [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) would work.

You can add any data type to the array, so inserting an array inside another is not a problem.